# Inconveniente con media query

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy modificando el css de mi proyecto y a la vez haciendo pruebas en vista previa del mismo solo que cambie el diseño y ahora tengo 2 media queries (una para móviles y la otra para tablet's) pero al guardar el archivo css cuando los 2 estan en un solo archivo se distorsionan varias partes como los textos aunque en cada uno de los media queries tienen diferente tamaño de fuente, y de igual manera se me modifican los tamaños de las imagenes que estoy utilizando.

En el html utilizo la etiqueta meta y el enlace a la hoja de estilos de la siguiente forma:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel=stylesheet href="../CSS/style.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
```

Y este es el contenido que se modifica:

```
<div class="cabeceraLogo" id="cabLogo">
    <a href="../HTML/index.html"><img class="logoPCM" src="../RSC/logos/logo.png" alt="logotipo PCM"></a>
</div>
<div class="cabeceraCentral">
     <p><b>todos nuestros precios son el mínimo en pagos al contado</b></p>
</div>
```

El css actual es:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Montserrat-medium-webfont',verdana,sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:360px) { 
   ...
   .cabeceraLogo{
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 3em;
      padding: 0.4375em 0.625em;
      background: #000;
      z-index: 80;
   }
   .logoPCM{
      height: 2.375em;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      vertical-align: middle;
   }
   /*-------------------------------------------------------*/
   .cabeceraCentral{
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1.5625em;
      background: #E6E6E6;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 11px;
      z-index: 80;
   }
   .cabecerCentral p{
      font-family: 'Montserrat-medium-webfont',verdana,sans-serif;
   }
   .cabeceraCentral p::before{
      content: open-quote;
   }
   .cabeceraCentral p::after{
      content: close-quote;
   }
   ...
}

@media screen and (max-width:599px) { 
   ...
   .cabeceraLogo{
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 3em;
      padding: 0.4375em 0.625em;
      background: #000;
      z-index: 80;
   }
   .logoPCM{
      height: 2.375em;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      vertical-align: middle;
   }
   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   .cabeceraCentral{
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1.5625em;
      background: #E6E6E6;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 0.68750em;
      z-index: 80;
   }
   .cabecerCentral p{
      font-family: 'Montserrat-medium-webfont',verdana,sans-serif;
   }
   .cabeceraCentral p::before{
      content: open-quote;
   }
   .cabeceraCentral p::after{
      content: close-quote;
   }
   ... 
}
```

También **tengo planeado aumentar 2 queries**, aunque no creo que tiene influencia estoy editando en Atom y allí mismo lo previsualizo.

**¿Qué tengo que modificar o qué me pueden recomendar?**

Comment: Para ver el problema, debes agregar todo el codigo necesario, replicando el problema. Esto se le conoce como [mre]

Comment: Estoy viendo tres puntos entre tu ```@media screen ``` que no debería estar ahí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede definir un mínimo y un máximo. Todo el estilo definido entre *360* y *599* seria para tu tablet.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 599px) { ... }
```